# How to select an element within a div to change the scale of another div using sibling combinators using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Within my personal project, my custom-created cursor will hover above the button and will change scale (transform: scale(3)). However, it doesn't seem to be working as I hope it would. Help?

My CSS for the cursor (the HTML is just an empty div)

```
.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.1s;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I want to be able to hover and see a change on the 'Send' button here:

```
<div class="contact-page">
    <div class="forms">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea name="message" id="txt-message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="send-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the button if needed:

```
.send-btn {
    width: 376px;
    height: 58px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

So far I have tried using this sibling combinator to try and get this to work but no luck so far:

```
.contact-page .send-btn:hover ~ .cursor {
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

I have also tried it with the '+' and the '>' just in case.

Edit: The .cursor HTML tag is located at the end of my body tag. It is the last element within the body tag. Does this matter?

Comment: I don't see your `.cursor` class ?

Comment: Where is the HTML for `.cursor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is your `.cursor` div is somewhere completely different which is why you didn't provide it.  It needs to be within the same level or deeper as the object you are trying to hover.  It is not possible in CSS alone to hover a "child" and effect a "parent".

So take a look at this: I added a `.cursor` div right below the button and the scale works.

```css
.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    transition: 0.1s;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 999;
}

.send-btn {
    width: 376px;
    height: 58px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.send-btn:hover ~ .cursor {
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-page">
    <div class="forms">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea name="message" id="txt-message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="send-btn">Send</button>
         <div class="cursor"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You're welcome.  Are you able to put the `.cursor` div in the place I showed you?  or will it not work for your needs there?  If the latter, you can use js to achieve the hover effect.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put the cursor div there as it messes up the whole functionality of my site. I'll try to see what I can do with JS but thanks again.